# instances acting like classes in rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I have code similar to the following as a after_create callback when a new account is created:

```
def after_account_create
  new_account = self
  logger.info( '%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     account is = ' + new_account.inspect)          
  assessment = Assessment.new :title => "Cake baking", :description => "Every day we bake fresh cakes to sell in our shop. This is our assessment of the risks involved in this process.", :account_id => new_account.id
  assessment.save!
end
```

When I run this on my development environment (Passenger / Postgres) it works fine - each time an individual signs up and creates a new account it creates a new assessment assigned to that individual's account.

However when I run this on my production environment (Thin webserver on Heroku) each time an individual signs up and creates a new account it creates a new assessment but assigned to the PREVIOUS individual's account.

Here are examples from the two logs when a second individual creates an account:

**Development**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     account is = #<Account id: 97, name: "Eric Clapton", plan: "Partnership", billing_zip: nil, no_of_users: 1, no_of_assessments: nil, id_of_admin_user: 90, created_at: "2012-04-05 14:58:54", updated_at: "2012-04-05 14:58:56">
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "assessments" ("account_id", "created_at", "description", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 97], ["created_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2012 10:58:56 EDT -04:00], ["description", "Every day we bake fresh cakes to sell in our shop. This is our assessment of the risks involved in this process."], ["title", "Cake baking"], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2012 10:58:56 EDT -04:00]]
```

**Production**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     account is = #<Account id: 2, name: "jack cale", plan: "Partnership", billing_zip: nil, no_of_users: 1, no_of_assessments: nil, id_of_admin_user: 2, created_at: "2012-04-05 14:46:54", updated_at: "2012-04-05 14:46:56">
(2.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "assessments" ("account_id", "created_at", "description", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 1], ["created_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2012 10:46:56 EDT -04:00], ["description", "Every day we bake fresh cakes to sell in our shop. This is our assessment of the risks involved in this process."], ["title", "Cake baking"], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2012 10:46:56 EDT -04:00]]
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed the `config.cache_classes` to `true` from `false` in my development environment and I'm getting exactly the same issue there now, so it definitely has something to do with that. I'm using this gem to scope the creation of objects to the current account only https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant could this be what is being cached between requests?

**UPDATE2:**
It was in fact exactly this. The current_tenant value was being cached between sessions. I had to add a method to the accounts_controller that defined the current_tenant value each time an account was created to the newly created account.

Comment: How does it behave with production settings in your development environment?  I'm suspicious of cache_classes=false causing your code to forget something you've accidentally memoized. How similar is what you posted to the actual code?

Comment: @BetjaminRichards Why not write this in after_save callback and check if it exhibit the same behavior any that behavior is any how weird

Comment: @BetjaminRichards I agree with @dbenhur I doubt setting `cache_classes=false` is the cause of the error